# pod lib lint complaints about header files outside of header_mappings_dir

Tags: header, cocoapods, lint, lib

I'm building a pod for an open source library and have to leave the directory structure for the public header files intact.
The simplified example is this:

```
include/header1.h
include/foo/header2.h
src/file.c
src/internal.h
```

The `include` directory contains the public headers.

My podspec contains:

```
s.public_header_files = 'Foo/Classes/include/**/*'
s.private_header_files = 'Foo/Classes/src/internal.h'
s.header_mappings_dir = 'Foo/Classes/include'
```

The `Example` project compiles fine and the `Pods/Headers/Public/Foo` directory contains the same structure as the original `include` directory.

Still `pod lib lint Foo.podspec --use-libraries` gives me this error:

```
- ERROR | [iOS] header_mappings_dir: There are header files outside of the header_mappings_dir (Foo/Classes/src/internal.h)
```

Well. Yes. Indeed. But why is this an error? I am totally fine with the situation.

I have found a solution myself, but I'm not sure, if it is the correct one.

```
s.exclude_files = 'Foo/Classes/src/internal.h'
```

This makes the linter happy and the project still compiles. But it feels wrong, because the file is part of the project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer this myself.

The `exclude_files` workaround did not work, when pushing the podspec to a git server.

The problem was actually a misconception: do not use the other path specification to exclude files you explicetely specified in the `source_files` line!

The solution was to explicitely only add the files to the `source_files` line, that are either part of the public headers or should get a compile rule in Xcode.

Any other files (headers outside of the `header_mappings_dir` and .c files that should be included but not compiled on their own) are added via

```
s.preserve_paths = 'Foo/Classes/src/**/*'
```

Now everything works.